# Javascript replace \\ to /

Tags: javascript, replace, imagemin

I am recently using imagemin npm to compress the image.
However if the image path is like

```
C:\\Users\\huzaini\\Pictures\\BlueStacks\\eeve.png
```

it cannot be executed and thrown error.
On the other hand when it comes to

```
C:/Users/huzaini/Pictures/BlueStacks/eeve.png
```

it is successful.
Therefore, I think of replacing \ to / instead. But I could not find the best regex. I tried this

```
.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")
```

but only the first \ changes to /

anyone can help me with this? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: `.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")` will _not_ only work on the first occurrence and it will also not replace ``\`` with `/`. Instead it will double every back slash in your string. Also why are all the backslashes in the first path escaped? It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: what does `yourInputPath.charAt(3)` return? A backslash or "U"? Just want to know what exactly we're dealing with here. Because if your string is `"C:\\Users"` then its content is `C:\Users`

Answer (score 1):

in regex `\` is an escape character. `\\` = `\` so you have to actually duplicate it. `.replace(/\\\\/g, "/")`.

test it on https://regexr.com/

Comment: maybe you could use this share link https://regexr.com/5a6qs

Comment: thank you, but it changes to `C:\Users\huzaini\Pictures\BlueStacks\eeve.png` and still imagemin npm cannot accept it. only `C:/Users/huzaini/Pictures/BlueStacks/eeve.png` will work :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `replace(/\\/g, "/")` .